# Tetris-style divisions of Square (NxN) boards

Tags: constraint-programming, tetris

When I was a child, I had a square board tetris puzzle, and the instruction said there are >15 thousand solutions. I've always wondered how they counted the solutions, and I'd like to replicate that.

So I would like to search for divisions of NxN boards into 4-cell and 5-cell fragments. Rotation is allowed, flipping is not.

- Problem A: Determine if a set of blocks can be assembled into a NxN grid.
- Problem B: Find divisions without rectangular subdivisions, except for single fragments (4 cells, that is, 2x2 and 1x4).

I'm thinking of constraint programming. But if I encode the presence of each wall as boolean, how can I efficiently count the blocks? Is it better to work in terms of fragments and check for rectangles later?

What other technique could help?

note: this is just for fun, and not homework or anything.

Comment: Don't you mean [Pentomio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino)?

Comment: @false yes, I'll start with this program. Thanks. https://github.com/toly/pentamino

Comment: Well, this program is brute force with pruning.

Answer (score 0):

I once challenged solving pentomino variant in Prolog.

Program:

http://www2.koyahatataku.com/programming/pent.txt

Result:

http://www2.koyahatataku.com/programming/pent_out.txt

I tried with naive brute force `Depth-first search` algorithm.